# static ints, compilation units and the ternary operator

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, undefined

// SomeCls.h

```
class SomeCls
    {
    static const int PERIOD_ALARM_NORMAL    =   5;          
    static const int PERIOD_ALARM_THRESH    =   1;          

    void method()
    {
        bool b = true;
        const int d = b ? PERIOD_ALARM_THRESH : PERIOD_ALARM_NORMAL;
    }

    } obj;
```

It is going to build ok. Now take out the method() implementation and place it in a cpp file:

```
 //SomeCls.cpp
#include "SomeCls.h"

void SomeCls::method()
    {
        bool b = true;
        const int d = b ? PERIOD_ALARM_THRESH : PERIOD_ALARM_NORMAL;
    }
```

Why does mr. linker say

> undefined reference to `SomeCls::PERIOD_ALARM_NORMAL'  undefined
>   reference to`SomeCls::PERIOD_ALARM_THRESH'

?

Thanks

EDIT:
It seems to me that that inside .h, the ternary operator takes static const ints it as rvalues but ... outside the decalrative .h, it regards them as lvalue and needs definition. 
This is what I have managed to understand from the answers below. Kudos to Bada compiler (some eabi linux thinggie)

Comment: Why does the linker say that when you do *what*? What are you trying to link exactly?

Comment: @Scarlet: I think you're misunderstanding something here. The OP doesn't want to test `d == b`, he wants to assign `d`, testing on `b`.

Comment: Please don't use all-caps for variable names. They're traditionally used only for preprocessor macros (apart from being very tiring to read).

Comment: @Xeo I'm blind :) Deleting comment not to create misunderstandings, thanks.

Comment: FWIW, this code works perfectly fine with Clang 3.1 but not GCC 4.4.5. Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a GCC limitation, but it's completely standard comforming.  Technically a `static const int` is still an `lvalue`.  You've provided the value inline so compiler will almost always use it as an `rvalue`.  There is one exception.  The abstract instructions emitted by the compiler for ternary operators queries the address of `lvalues`.  Hence the error you're seeing.

You can work around this by using `enum` instead.  Or if you're using a new version of GCC `constexpr` was added to standard to fix this exact problem (named and typed rvalues).

Alternatively you can provide the linker with a definition for the constants.  E.g. in your classes cpp file add the a line like

```
// I wish I had constexpr
const int SomeCls::PERIOD_ALARM_NORMAL;
const int SomeCls::PERIOD_ALARM_THRESH;
```

As a side note: I was a staunch proponent of `static const` for class scope constants.  Then I found out that MSVC doesn't allow for `static const float` with the value inline.  So the only values you can portably put in a `static const` are integers, in which case `enum`s provide all the same features plus the guarantee that they'll never silently convert to an `lvalue`.

Comment: that was plain egnlish. I just hope you are right with that lvalue / rvalue explanation and that I am picking the most accurate answer :P. Edit: seems it is not accurate. This does not explain how come it works in the first scenario - everything in .h

Comment: Inline initializations of non-integral types are only allowed for `static constexpr` in C++11. That has nothing to do with MSVC...

Comment: Note that it's only standard conforming with the previous C++03 standard. In C++11, the ODR wording changed: `§3.2 [basic.def.odr] p2` "[...] A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is *odr-used* unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) [...]". I'd very much say that a `static const int` *does* satisfy the requirements mentioned.

Comment: @KerrekSB,  I'd always assumed that `static const` inline initialization the standard only required a built in type not an integral type.  So it looks like GCC's allowing `float` was an extension.  Does the standard say that floats are allowed in `static constexpr`s?  Either way in preferred order (for compiler portablity) `static constexpr`, `enum`, then `static const integral`.

Answer (score 3):

If the compiler can't see all the static class constants' **values**, then you have to provide definitions for them so that they'll actually be stored somewhere. Add the following to your cpp file:

```
const int SomeCls::PERIOD_ALARM_NORMAL;
const int SomeCls::PERIOD_ALARM_THRESH;
```

Comment: +1, I did not know about the "if it can't see their values" part

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Well, it should probably be the other way around... "in good cases *you may not need a definition* because the compiler already knows the values and can fold them into the code without needing the actual variable"... I suppose having the function definition out-of-line is a sufficient reason for the compiler to insist on a definition.

Comment: Actual definitions in a translation unit should only be needed if he takes the *address* of those variables anywhere. He doesn't, so the example he gave should compile perfectly fine.

Comment: @Xeo: I think it's because the function is defined out-of-line, and so if you want to call the function from elsewhere, it needs that constant as a variable. Try it with `inline`, maybe then you get away without a definition.

Comment: @Xeo : Definitions in a translation unit are needed if he _'ODR-uses'_ those variables, which is not strictly limited to taking their addresses.

Comment: @ildjarn: But it also shouldn't be using them like the OP shows.

Comment: @Xeo : I tend to agree, this appears like a compiler quirk, I was just being pedantic regarding your comment. :-]

Comment: @Kerrek - have a look at deft_code's answer. The issue is somehow related to the ?: operator as I am able to use that static const int both in .h and in .cpp if not used with ?:

Comment: @kellogs: Possibly; I don't know if a true explanation exists: You're never promised that you don't need the definition, so you can't really complain when the compiler asks for it...

Comment: Holy ****it worked. So it seems that inside .h ternary op takes it as rvalue or something... outside .h, it regards it as lvalue and needs definition. zomg zomg

Answer (score 1):

If, for whatever reason, you compiler simply refuses to link the code (like GCC 4.4.5 does), here's a simple fix: Replace the `static const int`s with an `enum`.

```
// someclass.h
// include guards, blabla

class SomeClass
{
    enum AlarmPeriod{
      PERIOD_ALARM_NORMAL = 5,
      PERIOD_ALARM_THRESH = 1
    };      

public:
    void method();
};

// someclass.cpp
#include "someclass.h"

void SomeClass::method(){
    bool b = true;
    const int d = b ? PERIOD_ALARM_THRESH : PERIOD_ALARM_NORMAL;
}

// main.cpp
#include "someclass.h"

int main(){
  someclass sc;
  sc.method();
}
```

This links cleanly with GCC 4.4.5, which wouldn't link the former version, even though both are technically the same.

Note that you cannot, amongst other things, take the address of `PERIOD_ALARM_NORMAL` and `PERIOD_ALARM_TRESH` anymore, because both names are just aliases for their respective values.

Comment: But then the constants have a distinct, unnamed type.

Comment: @curiousguy: Happy? As if it'd make a difference in the example the OP showed.

Comment: It may not make a difference in this case, but it is a difference between `enum` and `static const int` that can impact code in a language like C++, and that could be surprising. I _think_ it is worth mentioning.