# C++ Ternary operator with scope resolution and condition

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ternary-operator

Following code is not being compiled by an specific compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
        public:
                static const int x = 12;
                static const int y = 16;
};

int main(){
        int a = 12, b = 19;
        int z = (a==b)?(A::x):(A::y);
        cout<<z<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Compiler **g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)** compiled it successfully.

Compiler **g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)** is causing compilation error

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `A::x'
test.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `A::y'
```

If I replace condition `(a==b)` in line `int z = (a==b)?(A::x):(A::y);` by `true` or `false`, then it gets compiled successfully.

What is the reason and how to fix it for specified compiler?

Comment: It looks like you've found a compiler bug that has been fixed.

Comment: The later compiler is probably able to optimize it all into `z = 16`. Take a look at the generated machine code to see.

Comment: Dd you compile with C++0x/11 turned on?  Cannot reproduce [here](https://godbolt.org/g/2eyWlM)

Comment: Look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568975/static-ints-compilation-units-and-the-ternary-operator

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a weak/buggy C++0x symbol-linkage implementation of gcc 4.4.
Seems that gcc 4.4 tells the linker that there are symbols but it forgot to "implement" them in one of the compilation units.

I guess if you put the initialization of the static members A::x and A::y  explicitly into one unique compilation unit (e.g. corresponding .cpp file) then your code may be compatible with both compilers.